# Why can I upload files with Formidable to folders using absolute path but not relative?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, relative-path, absolute-path, formidable

Like so many other newbies, I'm following along "The Node Beginner Book" by Manuel Kiessling.

We're supposed to enable image uploading through the Formidable module, constantly renaming the image to "test.png" and displaying it.

The book uses the path `/tmp/test.png` and everything works fine. But that is not a relative path, and my images are actually saved in my tmp folder in Linux!

I created the folder "tmp" in my project instead and tried to make the same thing happen there but I am only shown an error!

```
ENOENT, open './tmp/test.png'
```

The same thing happens when I try the path `tmp/test.png` but the funny part is that both these paths work when I put an actual image directly into the tmp folder and display it on my page. So there's not something wrong with semantics/syntax, or..?

My requestHandler.js, with the important part being the upload and show functions:

```
var querystring = require("querystring"),
fs = require("fs"),
formidable = require("formidable");

function start(response) {
  console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");

    var body = '<html>' +
        '<head>' +
        '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; ' +
        'charset=UTF-8" />' +
        '</head>' +
        '<body>' +
        '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" ' +
        'method="post">' +
        '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple">' +
        '<input type="submit" value="Upload file" />' +
        '</form>' +
        '</body>' +
        '</html>';

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write(body);
    response.end();

}

function upload(response, request) {
  console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called.");

  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  console.log("about to parse");
  form.parse(request, function(error, fields, files) {
    console.log("parsing done");

    fs.rename(files.upload.path, "./tmp/test.png", function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error Flynn");
            fs.unlink("./tmp/test.png");
            fs.rename(files.upload.path, "./tmp/test.png");
        }
    });

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write("received image:<br/>");
    response.write("<img src='/show' />");
    response.end();
});
}

function show(response) {
  console.log("Request handler 'show' was called.");
  fs.readFile("./tmp/test.png", "binary", function(error, file) {
    if(error) {
        response.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write(error + "\n");
        response.end();
    }
    else {
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "image/png"});
        response.write(file, "binary");
        response.end();
    }
  });
}

exports.start = start;
exports.upload = upload;
exports.show = show;
```

Worth noting is that the "Error Flynn" error message I specifically put there to troubleshoot **does** get called and the file I put in the folder deleted!

Here's the log:

```
Request for /upload received.
About to route a request for /upload
Request handler 'upload' was called.
about to parse
parsing done
Error Flynn
fs: missing callback Error: ENOENT, unlink './tmp/test.png'
fs: missing callback Error: EXDEV, rename '/tmp/upload_9bcb8afa8cd2f78ff52c294edd106965'
Request for /show received.
About to route a request for /show
Request handler 'show' was called.
```

Answer (score 2):

Relative paths work, but they are relative to `process.cwd()`, not the currently executing module.

`__dirname` is referencing the current `.js` file

Comment: Never heard of `process.cwd()` but I'll look it up. What's the syntax I should use?

Comment: Another unanswered question: How can it find the file to delete it using the same exact path but not rename it?

Comment: what I mean is that relative paths are relative to the directory of the node **process**. So the dir in which you started the node app. The `__dirname` is the syntax you can use, because this refers to de dir of the **file** in which it is used. This is a fairly common way of doing this...

Comment: you delete files with `fs.unlink()`. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback

Comment: Sorry man but you're not reading my questions and definitely not answering them. :) I know what unlink does. I don't know HOW it could do what it does when the PATH doesn't work. And of course I created the folder relative to the node process path already. So everything should work, except it doesn't. I would really like some clarity on this.